# C#, How to mock Azure Storage Method and Properties in nUnit tests

Tags: c#, nunit, azure-storage, .net-core-3.1, autofixture

I am working on nUnit tests for .NET CORE 3.1 Azure function with Azure Storage. I need to mock Azure Storage and need help on that!

I get collection of Azure Storage Files `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFile` in object `fileList` and then I am looping through it. Then I am calling `FetchAttributesAsync()` How can I mock `FetchAttributesAsync`, `SetMetadataAsync` & `ContentMD5`

```
if (fileList.Any())
{
  foreach (var foundFile in fileList)
   {
     await foundFile .FetchAttributesAsync();

     foundFile .Metadata.Add("Discovered", "true");
     await discoveredFile.SetMetadataAsync();

     var md5Hash = foundFile .Properties.ContentMD5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CloudFile` doesn't seem to implement those methods from any interface.
So, if you really want to mock it, you will need to wrap `CloudFile`. See below for the basic idea. Then you can mock `ICloudFile`.

```cs
public interface ICloudFile
{
   Task FetchAttributesAsync();
}

public class CloudFileWrapper : ICloudFile
{
   private readonly CloudFile _impl;
   
   public Task FetchAttributesAsync() => _impl.FetchAttributesAsync();
}
```